# Preserve view when switching sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to switch between sheets and have the same view on the next sheet.

As an example, I have sheet1 open and scroll to AD500 (-ish) and look at some values.
Then I want to compare those values (with my eyes) to the values at sheet2 at AD500 (-ish).
But when I switch to sheet2 it shows me the view I last had on that sheet.

Can they somehow be linked?
I have tried to find a setting for this but no luck. Can it be done with VBA?

Comment: You could try`View Side By Side` from the View/Window menu, or in VBA [`Windows.CompareSideBySideWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.windows.comparesidebysidewith).

Comment: @chrisneilsen True, But in my case I need the full screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no setting for this natively in Excel (but there should in my opinion) but you can kind off create this function in VBA.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next

    cell = GetSetting("Range", "visiblerange", "cells")
    zoomsett = GetSetting("Range", "visiblerange", "zoom")
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = zoomsett
    Application.Goto Range(cell)
    Application.Goto Range(Replace(Split(cell, ":")(0), "$", ""))

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    SaveSetting "Range", "visiblerange", "cells", ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Address
    SaveSetting "Range", "visiblerange", "zoom", ActiveWindow.Zoom
End Sub
```

This saves the visible range Address in the registry each time you make selection change on the sheets that have this code.
Then when you activate a sheet with the same code it first selects the full range, then selects the top left cell.
It has to select the full range to make sure it has the same view, then to "unselct" it selects one cell, the top left.
To make sure you have the same view it also sets the zoom of the sheets.

You could also make it select the same cell(s) you had selected on the previous sheet.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    On Error Resume Next

    cell = GetSetting("Range", "visiblerange", "cells")
    zoomsett = GetSetting("Range", "visiblerange", "zoom")
    sele = GetSetting("Range", "visiblerange", "selection")
    ActiveWindow.Zoom = zoomsett
    Application.Goto Range(cell)
    Application.Goto Range(sele)

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    SaveSetting "Range", "visiblerange", "cells", ActiveWindow.VisibleRange.Address
    SaveSetting "Range", "visiblerange", "selection", Selection.Address
    SaveSetting "Range", "visiblerange", "zoom", ActiveWindow.Zoom
End Sub
```

To use this you need to first add the code to all sheets you want this behaviour on, then save it as an macro enabled Excel file (xlsm).
Before you switch sheet click somewhere in the visible range then switch sheet.