# Add-In to Select Same Cell when Switching Sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create an add-in in excel that changes the active cell when switching sheets. So, for example, I have cell A1 selected on sheet1. When switching to sheet2, I want A1 to be activated again. I need this to be an add-in as I would like to use it across different workbooks (some with dozens of sheets) without having to go into VBA each time.

I have got to the code below that works when applying to sheets and modules. But I don't want to have to apply the code to each sheet individually, so I am looking at how to modify it to work out of a single module that can be saved as an add-in.

in Module:

```
Public addy As String
```

in each individual sheet:

```
Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    If addy <> "" Then
        Range(addy).Select
    End If
End Sub

Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    addy = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/create-application-level-event-handler) is a good place to start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preserve view when switching sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321277/preserve-view-when-switching-sheets) not a perfect match but may give you some hints.

Comment: @Andreas, although it is very close, it essentially does the same thing as my code above. Although this works, I want a solution that can be used across different workbooks by activating an add-in instead of pasting code

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx

Comment: @Tim Williams, AppEvent sounds great and would work well, but how would I need to alter my code above to work with it? Do I still need the second part in the sheet modules?

Comment: No all of the code would be in your add-in: you'd need to create `With Events` Application object, set it to the running Excel Application, then handle the required events  - eg see https://bettersolutions.com/vba/events/excel-application-level-events.htm for an overview

Comment: @Jonia54 there is a big difference between the two. Your code will not always give you the same view. The code I posted will. It will adjust the zoom, make sure the same cells are visible and select the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to capture your current coordinates?

```
'in module named "gvar" for global variables    
public r as long, c as long
```

capture whenever:

```
private sub fdsa() 
    gvar.r = activecell.row
    gvar.c = activecell.column
end sub
```

then later can use:

```
activesheet.cell(gvar.r,gvar.c).select 'on sheet activate
```

---

**edit1:**

above is good for a single cell, which is the posted example

if you have a range selected, you have to use `.count` to get you better...

```
'gvar
public rc as long, cc as long `r count, c count

private sub fdsa() 
    gvar.r = activecell.row
    gvar.c = activecell.column
    gvar.rc = selection.rows.count
    gvar.cc = selection.columns.count
end sub
```

then utilize such that

```
activesheet.cells(gvar.r,gvar.c).offset(gvar.rc-1,gvar.cc-1).select 'on sheet activate
```